# What happens when you apply a NOT to a universal quantifier

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

If I have $\forall x: P(x)$, what is the equivalent function if I attach a not to the whole function:

$\neg (\forall x: P(x))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the statement out: *not (for all x, p(x) holds)*. So if not for all x, there must be some x such that p(x) doesn't hold. So:

Then you have $\exists x : \lnot P(x)$.

Comment: So the existential qualifier is the inverse of the universal quantifier?

Comment: No, read what I wrote carefully. If that were true, it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean. So it would be like me saying not(for all x, x=2), therefore there exists some x, not(x=2)

Answer (score 1):

you'll have $$\exists x: \neg P(x)$$